# No animation for showing and hiding master UIViewController in UISplitViewController for trailing presentation (primaryEdge = .trailing)

Tags: ios, swift

So i have UISplitViewController with this configuration in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let splitVC = UISplitViewController()
    let masterVC = UIViewController()
    let detailVC = UIViewController()
    splitVC.viewControllers = [masterVC, detailVC]
    splitVC.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryHidden
    splitVC.primaryEdge = .trailing
    window!.backgroundColor = .white
    window!.rootViewController = splitVC
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

and since I use my master and detail VCs without navigation controllers, I wrote some functions for toggling(show/hide) master VCs in UISplitViewController extension:

```
extension UISplitViewController {
func showMasterView(from edge: PrimaryEdge = .leading,  completion: (()->Void)? = nil) {
    primaryEdge = edge
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
    }) { (animationFinished) in
        if let completion = completion, animationFinished {
            completion()
        }
    }
}

func hideMasterView(completion: (()->Void)? = nil) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryHidden
    }) { (animationFinished) in
        if let completion = completion, animationFinished {
            completion()
        }
    }
}


func toggleMasterView( completion: (()->Void)? = nil) {
    var nextDisplayMode: UISplitViewController.DisplayMode
    switch(self.preferredDisplayMode) {
    case .primaryHidden:
        nextDisplayMode = .allVisible
    default:
        nextDisplayMode = .primaryHidden
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.preferredDisplayMode = nextDisplayMode
    }) { (animationFinished) in
        if let completion = completion, animationFinished {
            completion()
        }
    }
}

func toggleMasterViewNew() {
   let barButtonItem = self.displayModeButtonItem
   UIApplication.shared.sendAction(barButtonItem.action!, to: barButtonItem.target, from: nil, for: nil)
}
}
```

These functions are awesome works with animation while splitVC.primaryEdge = .leading(by default), but not for .trailing - animation breaks down, master vc just appear for showing and hiding.
I know that i can write custom solution, but i want to know, why .trailing presentation broke toggle animation.

So, i hope we can find answer together :)